# drop selective columns pandas dataframe while flattening

Tags: python, pandas

I have a created a dataframe from a JSON but want to keep only the first 5 columns of the result.

Here is a part of the JSON:

```
{
"lat": 52.517,
"lon": 13.3889,
"timezone": "Europe/Berlin",
"timezone_offset": 7200,
"current": {
    "dt": 1628156947,
    "sunrise": 1628134359,
    "sunset": 1628189532,
    "temp": 295.54,
    "feels_like": 295.43,
    "pressure": 1009,
    "humidity": 61,
    "dew_point": 287.66,
    "uvi": 4.53,
    "clouds": 20,
    "visibility": 10000,
    "wind_speed": 3.58,
    "wind_deg": 79,
    "wind_gust": 4.92,
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 801,
            "main": "Clouds",
            "description": "few clouds",
            "icon": "02d"
        }
    ]
   },
   "hourly": [
    {
        "dt": 1628154000,
        "temp": 295.26,
        "feels_like": 295.09,
        "pressure": 1009,
        "humidity": 60,
        "dew_point": 287.14,
        "uvi": 4.01,
        "clouds": 36,
        "visibility": 10000,
        "wind_speed": 3.6,
        "wind_deg": 83,
        "wind_gust": 4.76,
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 500,
                "main": "Rain",
                "description": "light rain",
                "icon": "10d"
            }
        ],
        "pop": 0.49,
        "rain": {
            "1h": 0.52
        }
      },
      {
        "dt": 1628157600,
        "temp": 295.54,
        "feels_like": 295.43,
        "pressure": 1009,
        "humidity": 61,
        "dew_point": 287.66,
        "uvi": 4.53,
        "clouds": 20,
        "visibility": 10000,
        "wind_speed": 3.76,
        "wind_deg": 85,
        "wind_gust": 4.91,
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 801,
                "main": "Clouds",
                "description": "few clouds",
                "icon": "02d"
            }
        ],
        "pop": 0.55
      },
      {
        "dt": 1628161200,
        "temp": 295.58,
        "feels_like": 295.42,
        "pressure": 1009,
        "humidity": 59,
        "dew_point": 287.18,
        "uvi": 4.9,
        "clouds": 36,
        "visibility": 10000,
        "wind_speed": 3.58,
        "wind_deg": 95,
        "wind_gust": 4.73,
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 802,
                "main": "Clouds",
                "description": "scattered clouds",
                "icon": "03d"
            }
        ],
        "pop": 0.59
      }
     ]
    }
```

I have flattened the JSON first like this:

```
df_history = pd.json_normalize(data_history, max_level=1)`
```

That gave me this structure:

```
    lat     lon     timezone        timezone_offset     hourly                                              current.dt  current.sunrise     current.sunset  current.temp    current.feels_like  ...     current.humidity    current.dew_point   current.uvi     current.clouds  current.visibility  current.wind_speed  current.wind_deg    current.wind_gust   current.weather     current.rain

0   52.517  13.3889 Europe/Berlin   7200                [{'dt': 1627776000, 'temp': 17.82, 'feels_like...   1627855200  1627874869  1627930649  16.36   16.4    ...     90  14.72   0   0   10000   3.13    254     11.18   [{'id': 500, 'main': 'Rain', 'description': 'l...   {'1h': 0.17}
```

But I want to keep only the columns up to the column "hourly" and then flatten it.
I have tried this but to no avail:

```
df_history_small = pd.json_normalize(data_history, record_path='hourly',meta=['dt','temp', 'humidity'], errors='ignore')
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve my goal?

my final goal it to have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    lat     lon       timezone         timezone_offset  timestamp               temp    feels_like  humidity    pressure
 0  52.517  13.3889   Europe/Berlin    7200             08/01/2021 00:00:00     17.82   17.46           69          1005
```

Comment: After doing `df_history = pd.json_normalize(data_history, max_level=1)`, is `df_history_small = df_history[df_history.columns[0:5]]` what you are after?

Comment: almost :) Finally I want to flatten the "hourly" column as well so that the nested columns are shown next to the first 4 columns. Is that achievable too?

Comment: As each "hourly" entry is a list of dictionaries how exactly do you want to them flattened and stored in the DataFrame? Do you want a column, e.g, "hourly.dt" where each row  contains a list of each "dt" value in the original dictionary `[1628154000, 1628157600, ...]`?

Comment: @MattPitkin I have updated the question and added the sample of the final df. merci in advance ;)

Comment: @aerioeus. Can you post a valid json sample without ellipsis with `{ }` and ` [ ]` well balanced please?

Comment: @Corralien, you mean the JSON, right?

Comment: I have updated the sample in the question.@Corralien

Comment: I think you are mistaking the `meta` argument. That is not the columns you want in `humidity` record but, on the contrary, the information you want to get which is not in `humidity` record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
cols = ['lat', 'lon', 'timezone', 'timezone_offset',
        'dt', 'temp', 'feels_like', 'humidity']

out = pd.json_normalize(data_history, ['hourly'], meta=cols[:4])[cols]
```

```
>>> out
      lat      lon       timezone timezone_offset          dt    temp  feels_like  humidity
0  52.517  13.3889  Europe/Berlin            7200  1628154000  295.26      295.09        60
1  52.517  13.3889  Europe/Berlin            7200  1628157600  295.54      295.43        61
2  52.517  13.3889  Europe/Berlin            7200  1628161200  295.58      295.42        59
```

Feel free to convert `dt` to `timestamp` with:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(out['dt'], unit='s')
```